# Local application.conf with Play 1.2.5?

Tags: configuration, local, playframework-1.x

Is there a possibility to use a local application.conf with Play 1.2.5? Our problem is that different developers have somewhat different setups that we don't want to save to version control.

Alternatives found:

- Just modifying application.conf

  - Have to be careful not to commit changes to VCS
- Environments : Own environment for each developer : %john, %mary (saved to VCS)

  - OK alternative, even though we woudn't like to save those to version control
  - We have do change those during development every now and then -> would cause unnecessary changes
- @include : application.conf option for additional configuration files

  - [Play 1.2.5 documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/main#conf) : *This is an experimental feature that does not yet work properly.* :(

Something else?

Especially, is there a way to tell Play to use custom file name (as "conf/application.conf.local" instead of default "conf/application.conf"?

Comment: AFAIK Environments approach is only one possible in Play 1. In Play 2 it's possible to define alternative configuration file(s) (even remotely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered Play 1.x module [externalconfig](http://www.playframework.org/modules/externalconfig) that could help. Seems to work for our purposes. As an extra, this helps to keep production passwords etc out from the VCS.

Note that this module works only within Play's Java code - Play modules implemented in Python (as [migrate](http://www.playframework.org/modules/migrate), for example) won't be aware of external configuration. There might be concerns also with other Java modules that rely on `onConfigurationRead()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can append:

```
%my_play_id.@include.application.conf=my_application.conf
```

At the end of application.conf. One line per developer or environment. You can override some properties in my_application.conf and is not necesary to prepend %my_play_id to the properties changed. For example if you have three developers:

```
%developer1.@include.application.conf=developer1_conf.conf
%developer2.@include.application.conf=developer2_conf.conf
%developer3.@include.application.conf=developer3_conf.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the Play! 1.2.5 source code, but find nothing that suggests that Play! would be able to pick up anything other than the file `conf/application.conf`.

Comment: Look in `play.Play#readOneConfigurationFile`, there is a recursive logic to include other configurations for properties whose keys start with `@include.`.

Answer (score 1):

`@include` have worked for our setup where we import different environment configurations on play 1.2.5.

If your team is small, have each dev check in their own config each with their own prefixed user-key:

```
%[user-key].[property]=[value]
```

each developer will then have to change starting up play with

`play run --%[user-key]` instead of simply `play run`

Comment: Using this, would `play run` work directly if each dev runs `play id` in their sandbox?

Comment: it would work as long as you have the reasonable defaults set in application.conf.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is create a application.template configuration for the VCS that has the recomended configuration (instead of the actual application.conf).

This way every developer is responsible to create their own application.conf and to improve the template in the VCS.

This way no one mess with the deploy configuration and the configuration of the other developers.

If you want to version control the deployment configuration just add this to the tagged versions of your VCS